# How to get a pixel color outside of screen in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, pygame, pixel

I know that to get a pixel color in Pygame I use `get_at`.
But I need to get a pixel that is **outside** my screen, ie, I have an image already blitted with just a portion visible.

For example, a 1000x1000 image inside a 500,500 screen will only have 50% visible, the rest will be "off" the screen. So I need to access the portion off the screen.

But if I reference `get_at` with a coordinate greater or less then the screen dimensions, Pygame stops with an error:

> IndexError: pixel index out of range

```
import pygame
W = 1600
H = 600
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([W, H])
image = pygame.image.load('huge_background.png').convert_alpha()
screen.blit(image, [-5000, -420])
pygame.display.update()
screen.get_at([100, -5]) # generates "IndexError: pixel index out of range"
```

How can I get the background image pixel color outside the screen dimensions?

---

Here is the currently visible pygame screen (1600 x 600). The 3 lines (in magenta) are the collision "detectors":

[image]

And here is the background that will scroll (8000 x 8000):

[image]

So here is an idea of the scenario:
[image]

So, the collision detector lines might exceed the pygame screen limits but need to "read" the outside pixels to detect the collision.

Comment: You can't access pixels outside of the `screen`, because there are none. The screen is just a surface with the size of the window. You could access the pixels of the `image` surface that you blit outside of the screen. Could you explain why you want to do this? What's your actual goal?

Comment: I'm creating a race program and I the car needs to detect if is there any barrier ahead (for example, 500 pixels ahead). The car is always focused in screen and a background image (Speedway) is scrolling. But depending on the car's position, 500 pixels ahead will be out of the visible screen. But I know that the background image has the barrier or curves. So I need to "read" these pixels even if it's not being currently shown.

Comment: Okay, then you could access the pixels of the background image/surface and add the current offset to the pixel coordinates. You'd still have to make sure that the coordinates are inside of the surface area to prevent the error. Do have only one big background surface as the track? And you use the pixel color to check if it's a barrier or the road?

Comment: I've inserted some pictures and descriptions in the original post.

Comment: @skrx any idea how to solve this?

Comment: How do you scroll the background image? You need to adjust the pixel coordinates that you pass to `Surface.get_at` by adding the offset vector. I can't help much atm because I've got a headache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180494/discussion-between-skrx-and-rogerio-dec).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a stand-alone example that tracks the position of the view/camera on a larger background.

```
import pygame
W = 600
H = 400
pygame.init()
# generate repeated KEYDOWN events when a key is held
pygame.key.set_repeat(500, 50)  
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([W, H])

# image = pygame.image.load('huge_bkgnd.png').convert_alpha()

#create a large bkgnd image
bkgnd = pygame.Surface((W*10, H*10))
# draw a rainbow on the bkgnd surface
colours = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "lightblue1", "blue", "purple"]
bar_width = bkgnd.get_width() // (10 * len(colours))
for x in range(0, bkgnd.get_width() // bar_width):
    rect = [x*bar_width, 0, bar_width, bkgnd.get_height()]
    bkgnd.fill(pygame.Color(colours[x % len(colours)]), rect)

position = [0, 0]
clock = pygame.time.Clock() #for limiting FPS
finished = False
while not finished:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                finished = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    position[0] -= 100
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    position[0] += 100
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    position[1] -= 100
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    position[1] += 100
                # for all key movement clamp position to size of background
                position[0] = max(0, min(position[0], bkgnd.get_width() - W))
                position[1] = max(0, min(position[1], bkgnd.get_height() - H))
                try:
                    x = position[0] + W*2  # just look at what's to the right
                    y = position[1]
                    print(f"At {position}: Heading for ({x},{y}) {bkgnd.get_at((x, y))}")
                except IndexError:
                    print(f"Heading for the edge! {bkgnd.get_width() - position[0]} to go!")
    # copy bkgnd to screen
    view_rect = (*position, W, H)
    screen.blit(bkgnd.subsurface(view_rect), (0,0))
    # update the screen
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)  # limit FPS
pygame.quit()
```

Ignore the hacky-bit at the start to generate a rainbow background image so horizontal movement is obvious.

The program moves the position based on arrow key presses. Using `pygame.key.set_repeat()` it allows for the arrow keys to be held down.

There's a little bit of house-keeping in the event loop to ensure the view can't move outside the boundary of the background. Then it prints the colour of a pixel in the distance.

After the events are processed, a section of the background is drawn to the screen, based on the current position.

Let me know if you'd like any clarification.